# Problem with subclass parameter 'no suitable method found to override'

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a DataSourcesController that has the following methods:

```
public abstract ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataSource>> Add(DataSourceDTO dataSourceDTO);
public abstract ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataSource>> Edit(DataSourceDTO dataSourceDTO);
```

I have a SQLDataSourcesController that overrides those methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public override ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataSource>> Add(SQLDataSourceDTO sqlDataSourceDTO)
{ //code is in here }

[HttpPut]
public override ActionResult<IEnumerable<DataSource>> Edit(SQLDataSourceDTO sqlDataSourceDTO)
{ //code is in here }
```

However because of the SQLDataSourceDTO instead of DataSourceDTO I get the following errors:
`SQLDataSourcesController.Add(SQLDataSourceDTO': no suitable method found to override`
`SQLDataSourcesController.Edit(SQLDataSourceDTO': no suitable method found to override`

My SQLDataSourceDTO is a subclass of DataSourceDTO however:

```
public abstract class DataSourceDTO
{ //code is in here }
```

```
public class SQLDataSourceDTO : DataSourceDTO
{ //code is in here }
```

Any help on how I should fix this is appreciated!

Comment: How are you using the controllers? Where are you getting this error? Please, share the rest of code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the controllers are APIControllers. I get the error in the controller class. If I change that parameter type to DataSource instead of SQLDataSource the error dissapears, however, I think what I wrote should work since I'm passing in a subclass of the base class it expects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the method with a derived type as the parameter, because the signatures don't match. For overriding, the signatures should match exactly.

But you can use generic types instead.

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Controller<T> where T : Base, new()
{
    public virtual void Compute(T b)
    {
    }
}

public class SqlController : Controller<Derived>
{
    public override void Compute(Derived b)
    {
    }
}
```